# KQL List columns with a hit on specific text

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer, azure-sentinel

Need a query to be able be able to list the fields in the table that have text "mouse" and what that count is, for example:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3
dog      cat      mouse
cat      cat      mouse
mouse    bird     dog
```

Result for "mouse"

```
col_3   2
col_1   1
```

The practical application of this is to determine what fields in the Windows SecurityEvents log will have a computer name in them. As Azure Sentinel logs are not normalized there is no expectation to always find a computer name in the same place across all event types.

As an alternative we've had to feed event exports to a python script, this works just fine but doing this within KQL would certainly make things easier.

Can't find any alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out the below KQL ?

issue
| project col1, col2 , col3

| summarize col1 = countif(col1 == "mouse"),

```
        col2 = countif(col2 == 'mouse'),

        col3 = countif(col3 == 'mouse')
```

| extend Temp = bag_pack("Col1",col1,"Col2", col2 , "Col3", col3)

| mv-expand  kind= array  Temp

| project  Temp[0] , Temp[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35D9.png)

/////////////

Local testing output from my end:

[image]

Comment: This works but becomes impractical for a large or unknown number of fields. Because Azure Sentinel does not normalize messages, you just don't know what field a user ID, workstation name, or any other bit of data will be in.  Our goal was to be able to use some syntax to determine what fields might contain a workstation name for each different message type.  For example, in our case, the SecurityEvents log has a workstation name in 11 different fields across 12 unique event IDs, but there are 226 net fields across these event types. Taking an export into a Python script is able to tackle that.